# In ASP.NET, Can I Delete a row in GridView while the primary key of that table is not loaded into the gridview?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, sqldatasource

I have a table with primary key whose importance is technically high and none business wise. 
So, when I display the table data to user, I would like not to show him the primary key. 
Even if I load it in sqldatasource and dont show (I did this by removing the cloumn in "Columns" tag of GridView), I am not able to update or delete row using the built-in UpdateCommand & DeleteCommand. 
I have created the delete paramters but it does nothing when I hit the delete button.

How to get around it?

Thanks
R S Reddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I got this fixed by using DataKeyNames attribute in GridView. 
Just added primarykey of my table into it and everythings working like charm.

Thanks for your prompt help Babak.

Answer (score 0):

Use the primary key as the CommandArgument for the delete button. This say, you still have server side access to the value you need without having to expose it on the front end.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.commandargument.aspx